# Database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I forgot the password of a particular user in sqlplus 11g and I am trying to reset it as sysdba. I remember my user name and tried to execute this query: `alter user hr identified by Admin123;`

However the above query returns the error as

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Mis.png)

When I try to view all the users, it shows an error
[Error Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9guI.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st image it shows you have spelt "identifier" incorrectly